# json encoding of a float which as no fraction

Tags: json

What is the correct json encoding for a float value that has no fraction?

for example assume that I have:

```
float myValue=10.0;
```

what is the correct json encoding:

```
"myValue":10
```

or

```
"myValue":10.0
```

Comment: I don't think one's really more correct than the other. JSON doesn't really distinguish integers from floating-point. It just has one "number" format for both. http://json.org/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks. I looked at standard and I could not find any information about what is the standard format for numbers. Do you know where the standard defines how to encode numbers?

Comment: [json.org](http://json.org/) and [ECMA 404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) both include a [pattern diagram](http://json.org/number.gif) that describes the format of numbers. Walk it left-to-right, one character at a time. Each "fork" in the path represents a set of options for the next character (e.g., right at the beginning is an optional negative sign, `-`). Though, they don't specify how to arrive at this format, if that's what you're searching for.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks, I found and understand it. How different json encoders work on this case? for example, what c++, c#, java, PHP, ... encoding such number?